# In iOS 5, after the category changed, "AudioQueueStart" used 3 ~ 5 seconds to start recording

Tags: iphone, ios, avfoundation, ios5, avaudiosession

After I changed AudioSession's category from `kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback` to `kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord`, the `AudioQueueStart` method hanged on about 3 ~ 5 seconds to start recording.

The problem only happens on iOS devices running iOS 5, not in Simulator or the devices still running iOS 4 or iOS 3.

**Here is what I have tried:**

If I don't change the category but always use `kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord`, every thing works fine. `AudioQueueStart` start recording in about 0.01 seconds.
But because I want my sound come from the device's speaker, so I can not use `kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord` all the time.

Use `kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker` and `kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord` at the same time is a good idea but if I do so, I should also handle a lot of `kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRouteChange` situations such as the user plug in or remove a headphone, connect a bluetooth headset, etc. It is too complex.

Any advice or solution will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found a way to work around the problem which I believe is an iOS 5's bug.

I set category to `kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord` and use the code below:

```
UInt32 defaultToSpeaker = TRUE;
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryDefaultToSpeaker, sizeof(defaultToSpeaker), &defaultToSpeaker);
```

Note, the `kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryDefaultToSpeaker` id only available in iOS 3.1 or greater.